# How to enable Visual Studio (windows) and Docker (linux-image) to be run at the same time at the same folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

I have a strange problem:

For a project I made a docker Build-Container (Linux-Image).

If I build the project with the docker-image, while VS is running (at the same folder), both builds will fail because from autogenerated files will be windows or linux specific (Mostly about NuGet Paths).

In the project I set some flag, but they they did not work:

Line 19 and 20:

https://github.com/d-velop/dvelop-app-template-cs/blob/master/NuGet.config#L19

Any Ideas how I can stop VS from building automatically? Or can I separate the obj-Folders between windows and linux? This shuld also work.

For dy to day use this is not that big problem, because we run the docker image at a build server, but it is also meant to be used as an examplte project to test things.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Linux containers are run inside the MobyLinux VM (in Hyper-V). In order to create the image for the linux container, your project/solution directory on your Windows filesystem is lifted into the MobyLinux VM, and then the Dockerfile is run against those files (i.e. all the copy commands and such are relative to the MobyLinux filesystem, not your Windows filesystem). In short, there's no conflict, because they're not even looking at the same files.

Comment: The project is mounted into the container as volume. So they are using the exact same files.

Comment: Then that's your issue. Don't do that.

Comment: Can you refer to more information a link, good blog etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be that you're mounting your project directory as a volume and then sharing that between both the Linux container environment and the local Windows filesystem. That's a recipe for disaster.

If you were to add container support through Visual Studio, a Dockerfile like the following would be generated. This is considered a best practice approach for creating images for ASP.NET Core projects:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyProject/MyProject.csproj MyProject/
COPY MyProjectDependency/MyProjectDependency.csproj MyProjectDependency/
# etc.
RUN dotnet restore MyProject/MyProject.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyProject
RUN dotnet build MyProject.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish MyProject.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

This is a multi-stage build (as denoted by the multiple `FROM` lines). Everything except the final stage is discarded, which is why it's necessary to copy from previous stages (i.e. `COPY --from=publish /app .`). The end result is just as if you had simply copied an already published app into a plain `aspnetcore-runtime` image (i.e. no extra weight of build tools, source code, NuGet packages, etc.), but the project is entirely compiled and published as part of the image build.